# Managing Projects - What do you think about AxoSoft OnTime?

Tags: delphi, project-management, ontime

I am wondering what is your experience with AxoSoft OnTime issues tracking and project management solution in case you have ever used it (pros and cons)...

Cheers,
B.

Answer (score 2):

The. Client. Is. Bloody. Slow!

But yes, we use it. And it is powerful. And configurable.

But hell is the client slow!

Use the http(s) if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

same bugbears as everyone else is having with it. We use it for internal bug tracking and logging our time.

It seems very capable, and can handle what you throw at it, but I find the UI sucks, tabs flitting about the place and creating a new incident seems a case of fill in what it asks for, OK, then it'll error at you saying you need to fill in extra fields - some of which aren't on the tab it shows you. /whinge

Answer (score 0):

We use it and its got a lot of nice features - def some quirks, but since we have implemented it - it has kept us all on the same page.  It has some nice integration plugins to visual studio as well.

I would say its worth a go.

Sorry, just wanted to add: we use it for issue tracking only

Answer (score 0):

We use it for a small team of developers, and are very satisfied.  One of the best features is the SDK that lets you integrate it into your applications.  We use that to automatically submit defect reports in our error handlers, as well as a Request a new feature option on the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

Like Schmoopy, we use it on our team for bug tracking pretty exclusively.  For my personal impression of it, it does its job very well.  The client app could use a little usability improvement in the interface, but it covers all of our bases very well.